Switchboard Oracle on demand feed
I am trying to get the latest token price of a custom token on chain. For that, I am using Switchboard oracle. I have created my own feed. I have copied the program from switchboard docs but I am finding it hard to understand how to integrate into my own program and tests and my tests keep failing.
Here's my feed address: B4CZLmYN29E6EFmpRaH1Z9wqHFadHjFWiNb33NDALfQ8 (fetches the price of token)
anchor program
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use switchboard_on_demand::on_demand::accounts::pull_feed::PullFeedAccountData;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("55UNP19Hud9KPgNB8PzQjmhQWmgdZBakg2jCJ5M8jfUh");

#[program]
mod staking_updated {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.data = data;
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn test<'a>(ctx: Context<Test>) -> Result<()> {
        // Feed account data
        let feed_account = ctx.accounts.feed.data.borrow();

        // This is where you should verify that this account is specifically the one you're trying to read
        // Compare the public keys
        // if ctx.accounts.feed.key != &specific_pubkey {
        //     throwSomeError
        // }

        // Docs at: https://switchboard-on-demand-rust-docs.web.app/on_demand/accounts/pull_feed/struct.PullFeedAccountData.html
        let feed = PullFeedAccountData::parse(feed_account).unwrap();
        // Log the value
        msg!("price: {:?}", feed.value());
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Test<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub feed: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64,
}

test
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { StakingUpdated } from "../target/types/staking_updated";
import {
  PublicKey,
  Keypair,
  TransactionInstruction,
  Commitment,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as sb from "@switchboard-xyz/on-demand";

describe("staking_updated", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const staking = anchor.workspace.StakingUpdated as Program<StakingUpdated>;

  const feedAddress = new PublicKey(
    "B4CZLmYN29E6EFmpRaH1Z9wqHFadHjFWiNb33NDALfQ8"
  );

  async function myProgramIx(
    program: anchor.Program,
    feed_: PublicKey | string
  ): Promise<TransactionInstruction> {
    const feed = new PublicKey(feed_);
    const myIx = await program.methods.test().accounts({ feed }).instruction();
    return myIx;
  }

  const TX_CONFIG = {
    commitment: "processed" as Commitment,
    skipPreflight: true,
    maxRetries: 0,
  };

  it("Tests", async () => {
    const { keypair, connection, program } = await sb.AnchorUtils.loadEnv();
    const feedAccount = new sb.PullFeed(program, feedAddress);
    const crossbar = new sb.CrossbarClient("https://crossbar.switchboard.xyz");
    const results = await crossbar.simulateSolanaFeeds("devnet", [
      feedAddress.toBase58(),
    ]);
    for (let simulation of results) {
      console.log(
        `Feed Public Key ${simulation.feed} job outputs: ${simulation.results}`
      );
    }

    while (true) {
      const [pullIx, responses, _ok, luts] = await feedAccount.fetchUpdateIx();
      const tx = await sb.asV0Tx({
        connection,
        ixs: [
          pullIx,
          await staking.methods
            .test()
            .accounts({ feed: feedAddress })
            .instruction(),
        ],
        signers: [keypair],
        computeUnitPrice: 200_000,
        computeUnitLimitMultiple: 1.3,
        lookupTables: luts,
      });
      const sim = await connection.simulateTransaction(tx, TX_CONFIG);
      const updateEvent = new sb.PullFeedValueEvent(
        sb.AnchorUtils.loggedEvents(program, sim.value.logs)[0]
      ).toRows();
      console.log("Submitted Price Updates:\n", updateEvent);
      console.log(`Transaction sent: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx)}`);
      await sb.sleep(3000);
    }
  });
});


